# Long loading rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, postgresql, loading, passenger

I have an apache web server with passenger and rails
Also i have Postgresql

I don't change passenger memory consumtion configures, and by default, it has max 5 instanses.

My problem: In production environment some page loading very long (40 sec). It contains some SQL queries, i test every with EXPLAIN - that's fast. When I load the same page again - it loads very fast (1 sec). I don't use any cache services (as memcached).

In development env - I load the same page faster (in despite of 170ms DB queries).

How can I understand why page load so long? What should I change?

Comment: Is there an external asset that's waiting forever to load sometimes? For example an image hosted on a different server or a javascript coming from a 3rd party? These things are often flaky... you can inspect the web traffic in your browsers inspection or web developer console to help narrow it down.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just passenger spawning that takes this long? I believe that by default (at least it used to) it doesn't keep any children alive if there are no requests. So if you haven't used the app for a while and you do a request it needs to boot the whole rails process; this can take a while. Requests after this should be fast.

Comment: **pdobb**: I use a lot of external assets, but the first page loading long (only my HTML). Also I test that in ruby console - HTTP::Net.get (without loading images and process javascripts)
**Maran** I see that passenger has some instances in console after command passenger-memory-stats, it can has 1-5 processes contains path to my rails app. But i don't know how to check: Does it load whole rails app from stratch for first request? Where should I change it?